# Virtual scrolling on javascript

Tags: javascript, virtualscroll

I make virtual scrolling by using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SDa2B/4/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=SDa2B).

I can not understand how to get the real scrollable height;

If I change row size, it doesn't work.

And the if I made small size, such as 200, it doesn't work,too.

```
var s = 20000000                // row size
var rh = 50;                    // row height
var th = rh * s;                // virtual height
var h =  1000000;               // real scrollable height
var ph = h / 100;               // page height
var n = Math.ceil(th / ph);     // number of pages
var vp = 400;                   // viewport height
var cj = (th - h) / (n - 1);    // "jumpiness" coefficient
```

Comment: "$('#viewport')[0].scrollHeight "  this is display your scroll height

Comment: I want to know about this `var h =  1000000`;

Comment: `$('#viewport')[0].scrollHeight` this is giving you `var h` height. Check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/SDa2B/293/

Comment: is this helpful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$('#viewport')[0].scrollHeight` this will give you a height of the scrollbar.

Here is the JSfiddle link : [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SDa2B/293)

Comment: If anyone needs the [vanilla js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpLc09or/62/)